# Textfield's text inside AlertController generates crash only in iOS 11.0+

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, swift2

i have a following code which works in iOS 8.0+ to iOS 10.3, But crashes on iOS 11.0+ , i am unable to understand why

code:

```
 alertcontrol.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (textField) -> Void in

                    textField.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)
                    textField.placeholder = "Type Date as dd-mm-yyyy"
                    let endate = endDate.formatedDate("dd-MM-yyyy")
                    textField.text = endate
                    textField.textAlignment = .Left

                })
```

this code generates a crash at textField.text in iOS 11.0+, but this same code works in iOS 8.0+ to iOS 10.3
Also here endate always has an String output.

crash output:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

for code on endDate
inside NSDate extension

```
func formatedDate(format:String)-> String
{
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = format
    return formatter.stringFromDate(self)
}
```

output

> "27-10-2017"

Comment: does the log give a reason for the exception? Also check if your alert controller preferredStyle property is set to 'alert'

Comment: What is this line for    `let endate = endDate.formatedDate("dd-MM-yyyy")` May be it cause crash when date format isn't valid , Put Exception Break Point

Comment: How to get this one: `let endate = endDate.formatedDate("dd-MM-yyyy")` ?

Comment: endate does not gives any crash, when i print(endDate.formatedDate("dd-MM-yyyy")) it gives me the output in log, So, i definitely know that it contains a value

Answer (score 0):

What kind of `UIAlertController` style are you using? Adding text fields only work with `.alert`, not `.actionSheet`.